# Celery Beat how to calculate difference between datetime.now() and the next scheduled Periodic Task django

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

I have a celery beat cron schedule set for day 3 of every week.
In django shell I can access this schedule:

```
    >>> schedule = PeriodicTask.objects.get(name="Bulk Newsletter Send")
    which results in:
    >>> <PeriodicTask: Bulk Newsletter Send: * * * * 3 (m/h/dM/MY/d) UTC>
```

My question is, how can I calculate the time difference in days between datetime.now() and the next PeriodicTask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I am going to run with:

Derived from Celery docs [celery.schedules](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/reference/celery.schedules.html?highlight=is_due#celery-schedules)

```
periodic_task = PeriodicTask.objects.get(name="my_task")

time_to_go = periodic_task.schedule.is_due(datetime.now())

time_to_go.next = time to next run in seconds
```